# Knockout set attributes and click event

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-2.0

I did declare click like that in my template

```
<script id="flipTemplate" type="text/html">

    <div data-bind="attr: {id:  ImageName }, click: alert('a')">
    ......

</script>
```

But `alert('a')` executing straight away i clicking my button which is generated dynamic content instead of alerting when i am clicking on that div.

is there any way how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

knockoutjs expects a function as the [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) parameter not an arbitrary js statement.

So you need to wrap your alert call into an anonymous function

```
<div data-bind="attr: {id:  ImageName }, click: function(data, event) { alert('a') } ">
```

But I highly recommend to put every logic into your ko viewmodels and use the viewmodel methods in your bindings. So don't put logic into the `data-bind` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you are setting your Div up like this.  would this work better?

```
    <div id="mydiv"/>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#mydiv").click(function(ev){
             ev.preventDefault();
             alert("a");
           });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: just updated the Q, added some more details. I am dealing with dynamic content